# How to fix rollback transaction in laravel when used try catch in 2 model?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, try-catch, rollback

My rollback transaction doesn't work in my controller, when I used `try catch` in model?

Here in My Code

```php
try{
    DB::begin Transaction();

    $array = array("0" => "1", "1" => "2");
    for each($array as $data){
        $data = new Test();
        $save = $data->test();

        $data = new Second();
        $save = $data->test();
    }

    DB::commit();
}catch($e){
    DB::rollback();
}
```

Here in My Class

```php
public function test(){
    try{
        $log = new Test;
        $log->id = '20';
        $log->text = '30';
        $log->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

    }
}


public function second(){
    try{
        $log = new Second;
        $log->ids = '40';
        $log->text = '50';
        $log->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

How can I make rollback work with my code?

Comment: If you swallow the exception inside youy `test` and `second` methods, the code calling those methods will not recieve the exception, so the rollback will never happen

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception is happening in your `test()` and `second()` function and you have a try-catch there which doesn't let the exception come to the main function. Remove the try-catch from your `test()` and `second()` functions and it should work fine.

```
public function test(){
    $log = new Test;
    $log->id = '20';
    $log->text = '30';
    $log->save();
}

public function second(){
    $log = new Second;
    $log->ids = '40';
    $log->text = '50';
    $log->save();
}
```